# Shortest approach to avoid duplicate insertions without defining a composite key

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say there is a table `User` with Columns `Id, FirstName, LastName`.

Primary key is the auto generated `Id`

Is there a way to make sure that it doesn't allow to insert the same first name and last name combination to the table without defining a composite primary key based on those two columns.

Is there any other approach other than using an `EXISTS` sub query.

Comment: What's wrong with a UNIQUE constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Leave the ID as primary key and create a unique index on (firstname, lastname).

Comment: Oh my sir, he doesn't want to do that. Please read the question properly.

Comment: To add to this correct answer, when you are using a surrogate key you should always put a unique constraint on the natural key. (I prefer constraints to indexes because that implies a business rule rather than a performance tweak. An index is generally created to enforce the constraint anyway)

Comment: @Suraz, I'm guessing that he does not know the difference between primary key and unique keys in general. The stated restrictions are completely arbitrary.

Comment: @LoztInSpace, thank you for using the correct terminology and I'm glad that you added this comment. My answer does not mention constraints because the difference between constraints and indexes is not very well understood  :)